# MobilityRedirect to a different URL

Tags: 2007, mobile, redirect

I have a requirement to redirect a SharePoint web site to a custom built mobile site. MobilityRedirect feature allows something similar but for SharePoint. Is it possible to utilize this feature to redirect a SharePoint web site to, for example mobi.sharepoint.com instead of sharepoint.com/m?

Current solution to this would be a handler that detects a mobile device, and redirect to mobi.sharepoint.com, but if this is possible within SharePoint without a handler, would rather use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint have OOTB functionality to do this, but I wouldn't advice you to use it as it redirects to SharePoint OOTB mobile pages and views which is rather difficult customizing - depending on the purposes.

Through my experience it's better to create your own handler to detect devices (using UserAgent i.e) and use different stylesheets on different device (eg. mobile, tablets, desktop) which CSS Media Query can help you with.

Comment: that's exactly my thoughts around it as well. i tried to "override" the module for MobilityRedirect but this excepts only a single page, not a new url. thanks for your feedback.